# best mysql datasource properties for grails tomcat jndi

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails

Most examples of JNDI, mysql 5.6 and tomcat 7 have this defined in DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'
}
environments:
   production {
        dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/myDatasourceName
    }
}
```

and in the conf/context.xml in tomcat:

```
<Context>
   <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
      <Resource name="myDatasourceName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
       username="root" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db_name"/>
 </Context>
```

The question is, is this the correct setup for a basic low volume production system, which should reconnect if the db goes down then up etc?

In the DataSource.xml is a hugely complex example:

```
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        //url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10099;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        properties {
           // Documentation for Tomcat JDBC Pool
           // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes
           // https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html
           jmxEnabled = true
           initialSize = 5
           maxActive = 50
           minIdle = 5
           maxIdle = 25
           maxWait = 10000
           maxAge = 10 * 60000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
           validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
           validationQueryTimeout = 3
           validationInterval = 15000
           testOnBorrow = true
           testWhileIdle = true
           testOnReturn = false
           ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad = true
           // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors
           jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
           defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED // safe default
           // controls for leaked connections 
           abandonWhenPercentageFull = 100 // settings are active only when pool is full
           removeAbandonedTimeout = 120000
           removeAbandoned = true
           // use JMX console to change this setting at runtime
           logAbandoned = false // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging
           /*
           // JDBC driver properties
           // Mysql as example
           dbProperties {
               // Mysql specific driver properties
               // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
               // let Tomcat JDBC Pool handle reconnecting
               autoReconnect=false
               // truncation behaviour 
               jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
               // mysql 0-date conversion
               zeroDateTimeBehavior='convertToNull'
               // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementCache is used instead, so disable mysql driver's cache
               cachePrepStmts=false
               cacheCallableStmts=false
               // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementFinalizer keeps track
               dontTrackOpenResources=true
               // performance optimization: reduce number of SQLExceptions thrown in mysql driver code
               holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true
               // enable MySQL query cache - using server prep stmts will disable query caching
               useServerPrepStmts=false
               // metadata caching
               cacheServerConfiguration=true
               cacheResultSetMetadata=true
               metadataCacheSize=100
               // timeouts for TCP/IP
               connectTimeout=15000
               socketTimeout=120000
               // timer tuning (disable)
               maintainTimeStats=false
               enableQueryTimeouts=false
               // misc tuning
               noDatetimeStringSync=true
           }
           */
        }
    }
```

Now I dont know what 95% of those parameters do, but I guess I need them all?

What I dont understand is this

1. surely tomcat will pool the connections, so should pooled=true in the grails dataSource?
2. Surely tomcat will handle reconnecting and validation of connection, so why define validationQuery = "SELECT 1"?  Expecially as its saying "autoREconnect=false in the mysql dbPrperties section.
3. Could someone come up with a general purpose default dataSource definition suitable for mysql for a small number of users?  I can tune the min/max active/idle etc, but is this not all done in tomcat, not grails?
4. "userServerPrepStmts=false" why would anyone want to disable prepared statements?  We have been drilled for the last 15 years to only ever use prepared statements otherwise the DB cant cache them.
5. If I ignore all this complex example, and went with the super smiple one everyone posts, will it work properly?  e.g. will it reconnect when the db goes down and up?  will it not leak etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Tomcat has nothing to do with managing the database connection. Since [Grails 2.3.6](http://grails.org/2.3.6%20Release%20Notes), these are the recommended default datasource properties:

```
properties {
  //see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
   jmxEnabled = true
   initialSize = 5
   maxActive = 50
   minIdle = 5
   maxIdle = 25
   maxWait = 10000
   maxAge = 10 * 60000
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
   validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
   validationQueryTimeout = 3
   validationInterval = 15000
   testOnBorrow = true
   testWhileIdle = true
   testOnReturn = false
   jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
   defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
}
```

Comment: I have read other posts which say that when you use JNDI and tomcats database resource, what you put in properties here is ignored, as tomcat is managing the connection pool.  Its still not clear for me what to do in this case.  I suspect the above answer is if you are using Grails internal connection pool, not tomcats.