# should pooled=true or pooled=false for Grails using tomcat database resource via JNDI

Tags: grails, jndi, connection-pooling

When you use Grails to manage the MySQL connection, you need (in order to handle reconnections) a properties section along the lines of this in your DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    properties {
        maxActive = -1
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
        numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
        testOnBorrow=true
        testWhileIdle=true
        testOnReturn=true
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    }

environments {
    production{
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "upate"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb"
            username = "myuser"
            password = "mypass"
        }

    }
```

When you switch to using Tomcat's connection pool, most examples give this:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/revolve"
    }
```

**Question 1**

Should pooled=true or false in DataSource.grovvy for this type of connection (i.e. using tomcat), or does it matter?  There are posts saying it must be false, posts saying it must be true, and some not specifying it.  If set to True, this implies that there is a pool of pools, but this is what most examples are recommending.

**Question 2**

Is the properties section ignored?  If not, what are the recommended fields to be set.  From my trial and error, properties seem to be being ignored, contrary to posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062082/best-mysql-datasource-properties-for-grails-tomcat-jndi).

E.g. the validationQuery="SELECT 1" in the DataSource.java properties seems to be being ignored when using JNDI.  I.e. if I restart the DB, the app on Tomcat has permanently lost its connection to the DB.  If I add this same line in the Tomcat context.xml thusly:

```
<Resource name="revolve" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="50" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
    username="myuser" password="mypass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    validationquery="SELECT 1;"
    url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb"/>
```

and restart Tomcat, now if I restart the DB, the app on Tomcat continues to run.

This implies that the properties section of the dataSource in DataSource.groovy are being ignored when using Tomcat's connection pool.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to pool a JNDI DataSource, because it's a connection pool at the server, so you're pooling pooled connections. It's not a big deal, your local DataSource will just grab several connections from the web server's pool and "re-pool" them for your app, but this is unnecessary because the primary reason for pooling is to avoid the time it takes to get a real connection. This can take around a second, but isn't a long time but will affect performance. But the JNDI pool has already incurred that delay, so there's no benefit in pooling again.

Additionally you should omit the properties block, since those settings have to do with how your local connection pool works, but if you're retrieving pooled connections already, you don't need to configure initial size, max size, whether to test on borrow/return/etc., the validation query, etc. Those settings should be made in the configuration of the pool that you're making available via JNDI, and that would be done at the web server.

Comment: According to this answer, in an application using jndi datasource configured on a weblogic-server, following exception should never occur:
weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolLimitSQLException.
Regarding that it is occuring, would you please help in this regard?